# Change Content-type header in Kohana3

Tags: php, kohana

I'm trying to create a rss feed in my Kohana app. I did this in my controller:

```
public function action_rss()
{
    $games = ORM::factory('game')
        ->order_by('name','ASC')
        ->find_all()
        ->as_array();

    $view = View::factory('home/rss')
        ->bind('games', $games);

    $this->request->$headers['Content-type'] = 'application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8';

    $this->request->response = $view;
}
```

It doesn't work (when I remove the $headers line, it does, but with a html type). How can I send the response as rss+xml ?

Thank you.

Comment: It's `Content-Type`, not `Content-type`, according to the spec. Nitpicking, I know.

Comment: One thing that might be worth noting is that Kohana 3 has a built in RSS helper.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to replace the charset with `Kohana::$charset`. You never know... :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work if you get rid of the `$` in `$headers`.